# Can Doxygen generate TODO-like lists for arbitrary keywords?

Tags: doxygen, documentation-generation

Doxygen has the [\todo](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdtodo) command which produces documentation that shows up in the function it resides in and also gets aggregated into a global Todo List document.

Can this behavior be duplicated or simulated for arbitrary other tags? I would like to do something like "\tag XXX" and the have that comment aggregated into a global "XXX List" document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can create your own tag lists.
See http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem.